# Applying a Paypal Web Pofile disables "Check out as a Guest"

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to create a paypal payment page, but for some reason when I try to add a custom web profile to the payment the option of checking out as a guest suddenly disappears.

First I am creating the web profile this way:

```
        $flowConfig = new FlowConfig();
        $flowConfig
            ->setLandingPageType("billing")
            ->setBankTxnPendingUrl("...");
        $presentation = new Presentation();
        $presentation
            ->setLogoImage("...")
            ->setBrandName("...")
            ->setLocaleCode("...");

        $inputFields = new InputFields();
        $inputFields
            ->setNoShipping(1)
            ->setAddressOverride(0);

        $webProfile = new WebProfile();
        $webProfile->setName("PROFILE" . uniqid())
            ->setFlowConfig($flowConfig)
            ->setPresentation($presentation)
            ->setInputFields($inputFields);
        $request = clone $webProfile;

        try {
            $createProfileResponse = $webProfile->create($apiContext);
        } catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
            ...
        }
        $profileId = $createProfileResponse->getId();
```

Then, I have updated the payment code in this way

```
        $paypalPayment = new PayPalPayment();
        $paypalPayment->setIntent("sale");
        $paypalPayment->setPayer($payer);
        $paypalPayment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
        $paypalPayment->setTransactions(array($transaction));
        $paypalPayment->setExperienceProfileId($profileId);
```

The weird thing is that if I comment the last line I can perform payments as a guest without any issue. If, instead, I leave it this way, I get the customized page but the "Check out as a guest" button is replaced by "Create an account".

Do I really have to choose between having a customized checkout page and the possibility to perform payments without creating paypal accounts? Or am I missing something? I didn't find anything related to this issue in the documentation nor here in stackoverflow, and it seems at least strange!

Thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, I am trying to make simple one-time payments, by following the example at http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html and http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/ExecutePayment.html

The only difference from that code is that I am trying to add a custom web profile, with the issues described

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Express Checkout? It looks like recurring payments without a PayPal account are only compatible with Website Payments Pro accounts.

You can still create recurring payments with EC but they will need a PayPal account to accept them, no guest checkout allowed by the looks of it.

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/How-to-accept-recurring-payments-from-buyers-who-don-t-have-a/td-p/178232

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! If I am not mistaken, the Express Checkout was a mode of the classic APIs, while I am using the REST APIs to perform simple, one-time payments. Sorry for not stating that in the description :(